# Attaching multiple target group to AutoscalingGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I'm designing a infrastucture solution to balance traffic to 2 different webapps, hosted in the same instance by different paths and ports.

Im trying to do a Cloudformation to create an ALB, 1 listener, 2 target groups pointing to the instance that Autoscaling Group create, and 2 different listener rules with both targetgroups.

As i read in AWS documentation, i must define inside AutoSG properties, the target groups, but i'm having problems to define it.

I'm not sure either, that im doing correcty.

I'm getting error message using this code (I think that this is the wrong part, when i do the reference in the autoscaling group creation, to the target groups)

```
       "TargetGroupARNs": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "DefaultTG"
                    },
                    {
                        "Ref": "SecondTG"
                    }
        ],
```

Those Target groups are defined like that:

```
 "DefaultTG" : {
          "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
          "Properties" : {
          "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
          "HealthCheckProtocol": "HTTPS",
          "HealthCheckPath": "/home",
          "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 10,
          "HealthyThresholdCount": 4,
          "Matcher" : {
          "HttpCode" : "200"
          },
          "Name": "Default",
          "Port": 4443,
          "Protocol": "HTTPS",
          "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 3,
          "VpcId": {"Ref" : "VpcID"}
    },
```

The code of listener and one listener rule:

```
   "ALBListener": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties": {
        "DefaultActions": [{
        "Type": "redirect",
            "RedirectConfig" : {
            "TargetGroupArn": { "Ref": "DefaultTG" }
            }
        }],
        "LoadBalancerArn": { "Ref": "APIServerELB" },
        "Port": "443",
        "Protocol": "TCP"
       }
    },
    "DefListenerRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule",
      "Properties": {
          "Actions": [
                    {
                     "Type": "forward",
                     "TargetGroupArn": {
                     "Ref": "DefaultTG"
                    }
            }
            ],
          "Conditions" : [
                {
                  "Field" : "path-pattern",
                  "Values" : [ "/home" ]
                }
              ],
                "ListenerArn": {
                    "Ref": "ALBListener"
                }
          }
    },
```

And the error is:

```
Template validation error: Invalid template resource property 'DefaultTG'
```

I expect that the Cloudformation create one ALB with listener and 2 listener rules using 2 target groups pointing to the instances created by Autoscaling group.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. I have the following within my `Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'` and it works.

I couldn't figure it out with one ALB, so I have two ALB.

```
"TargetGroupARNs": [
    {
        "Ref": "DefaultTG"
    },
    {
        "Ref": "APIServerELB"
    }
],
```